# Angular-Material 1 inch blank space above toolbar

Tags: angular-material

I noticed that when I use an Angular Material toolbar on Chrome, I get about a 1 inch blank space at the top of the window (page, modal, dialog, etc...).  How do I remove this?

[image: Blank Space above Toolbar]

Code producing the Modal:

```
<md-dialog aria-label="Game Info and Map">
    <md-dialog-content>
        <md-toolbar flex layout="row" layout-align="space-between center">
            <img ng-src="{{schedule.HomeTeamLogo}}" class="TeamLogo" alt="{{schedule.HomeTeamName}} Logo" />
            <h5>{{schedule.GameDate | SLS_Date}} @ {{schedule.GameTime | SLS_Time:'hh:mm'}}</h5>
            <img ng-src="{{schedule.AwayTeamLogo}}" class="TeamLogo" alt="{{schedule.AwayTeamName}} Logo" />
        </md-toolbar>
        <section layout="column" layout-align="center">
            <div ng-init="coords={latitude: false, longitude: false}">
                <gm-map options="{center: [{{schedule.Latitude}}, {{schedule.Longtitude}}], zoom: 13, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP}">
                    <gm-marker options="{position: [{{schedule.Latitude}}, {{schedule.Longtitude}}], draggable: false}">
                        <gm-infowindow options="{content: '{{schedule.VenueName}}'}"></gm-infowindow>
                    </gm-marker>
                </gm-map>
            </div>
        </section>
    </md-dialog-content>    

    <section>
        <div class="md-actions">
            <md-button ng-click="CloseDialog()" class="md-fab md-fab-bottom-right md-mini" aria-label="Close"><ng-md-icon icon="close"></ng-md-icon></md-button>
        </div>
    </section>
</md-dialog>
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/UNH5WdMpOK5X3W9HW0uS?p=preview)

Comment: It is a little hard to visualize how you are using toolbar, would you mind posting the piece of code somewhere?

Comment: @bobleujr I have added the Modal HTML template code.

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle/plunkr for your code snippet?

Comment: @PraveenSingh This code is opened into a $mdDialog using the templateUrl reference. This is the complete code.  I might be able to mock up a sample that will work.

Comment: @PraveenSingh Added a plunkr with basic information to show large white space about toolbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steven,

It seems to me that your md-action css class has a `min-height: 52px`. A little strange but you can work this around in your css. Try something like on this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/A2aZTVCT9vKI93JAHS3Q?p=preview). If this css change affects more than it should, try specializing your css like adding a new class or so.

hope it will help :)

Comment: Thanks, that does help. What is interesting though is that I am using the default Angular-Material CSS.  I guess they intend this space to be there. I am getting it everywhere.

Comment: I believe that too. I was taking a look at their demo and it seems to be some sort of a title bar. Anyway, I am glad this helps.

Comment: The interesting thing, remove all the <section> I had for the scrolling, has been the cause, so once it was removed, the page renders correctly.  What is interesting though, is that the main application has the same spacing, without sections. Seems to be something about toolbars, etc...